# How to open a JAR file in J developer

Tags: oracle-adf

i am using Jdeveloper (11.1.1.6.0) and i have a JAR file which is used to connect to OIM
I need help to setup this.

i need to know what kind of service calls i make that is why i need to setup all these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

project properties->Libraries and ClassPath -> Add JAR
Will add the Jar file to your project - then you can use the classes in it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Shay'a answer you can read this blog https://blogs.oracle.com/sfehrman/entry/programmatically_provisioning_users_via_oracle To help you getting started.

Comment: Hi @TimoHahn the link you have sent helped me a lot, Is their any similar method for Select(particular item or application) and set (assigning any duties or roles). Thank you for your time